# knex.js - migrate latest 'Already Up To Date'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

When I run knex migrate: latest, I get the following, "Already up to date".

You see, I previously ran successful migrations, but then I used the mySQL CLI to delete those tables, because I was getting this 'Already up to date' message.  I thought deleting the tables would force knex to recognize it wasn't up to date.  Didn't work.

Any pointers?

Here are my files:

knexfile.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST_DEV || '127.0.0.1',
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER_DEV,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD_DEV,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME_DEV
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'recipes'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname+'/database/migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Migrations:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.hasTable('recipe').then((exists) => {
            if (!exists) {
                knex.schema.createTable('recipe', (table) => {
                    table.uuid('id');
                    table.string('name');
                    table.string('description');
                })
            }
        }),
        knex.schema.hasTable('ingredient').then((exists) => {
            if (!exists) {
                knex.schema.createTable('ingredient', (table) => {
                    table.uuid('id');
                    table.string('name');
                })
            }
        }),
        knex.schema.hasTable('recipe-ingredient').then((exists) => {
            if (!exists) {
                knex.schema.createTable('recipe-ingredient', (table)=> {
                    table.foreign('recipe_id').references('recipe.id');
                    table.foreign('ingredient_id').references('ingredient.id');
                    table.string('qty');  // <-- chose string instead of int because receipes include qty such as '1/3 cup', '1 teaspoon', etc.
                })
            }
        })
    ])
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.dropTable('recipe-ingredient'),
        knex.schema.dropTable('ingredient'),
        knex.schema.dropTable('recipe')
    ])
};
```

Comment: A little extra info: I manually deleted my database using the MySQL CLI.  then when I run the latest migration, it appears to run: `Batch 1 run: 4 migrations`.  BUT, when I execute "show tables" via MySQL CLI, it only shows the `knex_migrations' and the 'knex_migrations_lock' tables.

Comment: If the cli for `knex` is like that of `sequelize`, it might keep track of which migrations have been run in some sort of `migrations` table (perhaps the `knex_migrations`?). Perhaps `knex` is looking at all of your available migration files, recognizing that they all have entries in your `knex_migrations` table, and refusing to run them. I wonder if you change the name of your migration file or try to manually delete its entry in `knex_migrations` (if it's there), if knex will run the migration file for you again.

Comment: @therobinkim thanks Robin.  I've finally learned that when this happens, I need to delete the records in the knex_migrations table, and delete the migration files in the repo, create new migration files, and run them.  This seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to delete the logs of any migrations with the same name as the previous as your current migration in question, I had the same issue on postgres a while back.

Comment: To be specific, delete the `knex_migrations` and `knex_migrations_lock` tables. (actually, you should be able to delete just the row in `knex_migrations` for the migration files you want to rerun)